# Button Style background color not working - XML only

Tags: android

Im trying to set a background color from the style xml depending if the state of the button is enabled or not.

Button XML:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                    style="@style/SuccessButton2"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="Iniciar sesión"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    />
```

Style SuccesButton2:

```
<style name="SuccessButton2" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/button_background_color</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/myriad_pro_regular</item>
</style>
```

XML button_background_color:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/dark_gray"/>
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/red"/>
```

i have the same for the Text and its working fine:

button_text_color:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#4E4E4E"/>
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
```

The background item its not working, it show the button with a transparent background only, enabled or not.

Comment: Solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **`android:backgroundTint`** .

> Tint to apply to the background.

```
 <item name="android:background">@color/button_background_color</item>
 <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/button_background_color</item>
```